# scatter3d(): chol.default(shape) error: leading minor of order not positive definite

Tags: r, pca, scatter3d, scatterplot3d

I am currently trying to do a principle coordinate analysis (PCoA) in R. I am very new to R and am still trying to learn syntax and code. I was successful in running the PCoA and got it to plot, and am now trying to visualize the PCoA in a 3D space using the scatter3d() function.

I successfully ran the PCoA with the following code

```
#Running the PCoA
library(vegan)
library(labdsv)

Gowerdist <- vegdist(data.frame,method="gower", na.rm= TRUE)
pcotest <- pco(Gowerdist,k=4)
summary(pcoaTESTplot)
write.csv(pcotest$points,'pcotestPOINTS.csv')

#Plotting PcoA
library(ggplot2)
pcoaTESTplot <- read.csv("pcotestPOINTS.csv")
ggplot(pcoaTESTplot, aes(x=V1, y=V2, color=Species)) + geom_point() + geom_text(aes(label=Species),hjust=0, vjust=0)
```

The pcotestPOINTS.csv plots normally in a 2D plane and I group it by Species, and has the following values (I am new to R, and do not know how to write this out as code; suggestions would be helpful):

```
 Species           V1           V2           V3           V4
1     cf_M -0.031781895 -0.014792286 -0.004503777 -0.012610220
2        C -0.091464004 -0.134006338 -0.017100030  0.049538102
3        C -0.142280811 -0.071970920  0.057220986  0.015636930
4        G  0.127901175 -0.056155450 -0.018575333  0.015381534
5        G  0.116318613 -0.125552537  0.036418773 -0.098754726
6        G  0.212966778 -0.097406669 -0.023185002  0.081309634
7        G  0.063114834 -0.052422944 -0.027281979 -0.013183572
8        G  0.164193441 -0.145067313  0.047893500 -0.075261012
9        G  0.125573983 -0.030635914 -0.003522366  0.055693725
10       C -0.175866887 -0.049829963 -0.032233067  0.033557543
11    cf_M -0.135541377  0.055739251 -0.089503580  0.048764398
12       C -0.177278483 -0.022729224 -0.036536839  0.056107016
13       C -0.213010465 -0.048179837 -0.066925006  0.044377553
14       C -0.150118314 -0.011262976  0.052875986  0.078814272
15       C -0.052938204 -0.032302610  0.031115540  0.041222419
16    cf_M -0.060527464  0.047843822 -0.032686702 -0.116874986
17    cf_M -0.104463064 -0.056349285  0.031957309 -0.059974654
18       C -0.110412784 -0.023630954  0.005149408  0.044280367
19    cf_M -0.120946082  0.060083837 -0.085371294 -0.130249238
20    cf_M -0.052607412 -0.035729934  0.034557754  0.039291800
21       M -0.098428805  0.227005817  0.012707286  0.015943080
22       G  0.111732258 -0.105793117 -0.078062124  0.018757562
23       G  0.104440727 -0.043103550 -0.054803773  0.040568053
24       G  0.114630615 -0.102812853  0.029796076 -0.025098120
25    cf_G  0.041189558 -0.109686712 -0.081449510  0.012694654
26       G  0.139372615 -0.073429675 -0.035514832 -0.021797285
27    cf_G  0.049630172 -0.120238042 -0.082500823 -0.025354457
28       G  0.131962913 -0.079345351 -0.038031678  0.032418512
29       G  0.145388151 -0.073033647 -0.006097915  0.016838026
30       G  0.153083521 -0.080719015  0.009411666  0.013890614
31       G  0.163658995 -0.056128193  0.014838792  0.019248676
32       G  0.175740848 -0.055809349 -0.085783874  0.042118869
33       M  0.122374853  0.121760579  0.000972723 -0.048284135
34       M  0.073623753  0.083966711 -0.048553107  0.014595662
35    cf_M  0.002493609 -0.019775472  0.048228606 -0.107557856
36    cf_M -0.142542791 -0.048504297 -0.033862597  0.014891024
37       M  0.073067507  0.175692122 -0.032429380 -0.013033796
38       M  0.049394837  0.048055305 -0.048492332  0.024362833
39       M  0.043374473  0.148914450 -0.071568319  0.076386040
40       M  0.100479924  0.101136266 -0.000714071  0.069775037
41       C -0.095274095 -0.066087291  0.126446794 -0.054039041
42       C -0.050515560 -0.075369130  0.075846115  0.004257934
43    cf_C -0.120209368 -0.044737012 -0.015814314  0.029790605
44       M  0.033819722  0.077098451  0.103200615  0.001797658
45       M  0.099041728  0.127793360  0.123679516 -0.092233055
46       C -0.119684548 -0.071573066  0.020774450  0.045440300
47       M  0.080064569  0.158117147  0.050984478  0.049517871
48       M  0.073061563  0.179736841  0.061438231 -0.085872914
49       M  0.066196996  0.126650019 -0.073256733  0.050736463
50       M -0.017180859  0.092915512 -0.062340826  0.030966866
51       M  0.007313941  0.030544171  0.034107786 -0.008451064
52       M  0.030077136  0.091946729  0.019021861 -0.037148376
53       M  0.181104379  0.154261866  0.184970234  0.152371966
54    cf_M -0.076461621  0.038913381 -0.094850112 -0.075737783
55    cf_M -0.077452675  0.058624603 -0.104210238 -0.028904142
56       C -0.136410016 -0.068696015  0.032681381  0.027559673
57    cf_M -0.084262114  0.025497711 -0.046012632 -0.090147470
58       C -0.099403208 -0.049318827  0.047823149 -0.074616210
59    cf_C -0.151949338  0.003355951 -0.074866137  0.026535190
60       M -0.048272207  0.035885684 -0.036572954 -0.024464274
61       M  0.035272332  0.137994016  0.048921034 -0.033152910
62       M  0.061062726  0.088220032  0.027235884  0.006511185
63    cf_M -0.022678804  0.096566014 -0.089668642 -0.032362149
64       M  0.100783139  0.070006730  0.086195185 -0.022204185
65    cf_C -0.009137953  0.017062431 -0.050115368 -0.133785442
66    cf_M -0.107810732 -0.068024004  0.021125172  0.021052237
67       G  0.095668772 -0.138675431 -0.028579849 -0.076913412
68       M -0.027020841  0.069674169 -0.021508615  0.032142949
69       C -0.226937501 -0.080085817  0.216765725  0.015425306
70       G  0.203314776 -0.110344554  0.079133253  0.040076830
71       C -0.153490987 -0.013755267  0.165370191 -0.036327947
72       G  0.113580066 -0.166450142 -0.014627538 -0.018557855
73       M -0.132917211  0.008685202  0.031339457  0.058982043
74    cf_M -0.000375639  0.030195173 -0.024656948  0.018778677
75       C -0.159551518 -0.026830563 -0.020288912  0.049217439
76       M  0.057460058  0.096136625  0.006413249 -0.029953721
77    cf_M -0.066324419  0.070271569 -0.083959037  0.025280882
```

When I use the scatter3d() function:

```
library(scatterplot3d)
library(plot3D)

scatter3d(x = pcoaTESTplot$V1, y = pcoaTESTplot$V2, z = pcoaTESTplot$V3,
          point.col = "blue", groups = pcoaTESTplot$Species, ellipsoid = TRUE, grid = TRUE, surface = FALSE)
```

I get all species plotted but only the "C" species gets an ellipse, along with the error

> Error in chol.default(shape) : 
>     the leading minor of order 3 is not positive definite

I have tried changing rearrange values or see if it has to do with values being close to zero, but I know someone who ran the same code with similar numbers and all groups had an ellipse. I also tried taking the "cf_G" which only has 2 points and grouping it with "G" to see if there was an error due to an ellipse trying to be formed on two points, but I still got the same error. Does anyone know what the error is coming from? Thank you! (Apologies for any rough code/syntax...)

Answer (score 0):

Making this answer in case it will help others:

I have found the solution. I thought by combining the "cf_G" with the "G" would fix the issue, as "cf_G" only has two points. This didn't fix the issue because this was only part of the problem. I had to do this, as well as combine the "cf_C" with the "cf_M" because "cf_C" only had 3 points. So some of my groupings did not have enough points to plot the ellipsoid. And fortunately, this makes biological sense with how I made these species groupings.

So the aforementioned changes that were made were done by editing column 1 in the PCoA file with the gower distances.